# Can I trust ZipInfo.file_size?

Tags: python, zip, filesize

`ZipInfo.file_size` contains the size the uncompressed file in ZIP archive. May I be 100% sure, that the file will have this size after extraction, is it possible to fake it?

I am trying to allow users to upload big files in ZIP archive. I check `ZipInfo.file_size` to prohibit files larger than 1GB, and would like to protect the file system from zip-bombing, when after extraction from ZIP archive file having `ZipInfo.file_size < 1GB` is actually 1000GB.

Comment: What makes you think it's not reliable?

Comment: Because it's just a number stored in ZIP file headers. Imagine that someones packs 100GB file and then manually edits ZIP file to change extracted size to 100 bytes.

Comment: If that's what you believe, then you have your answer I guess. But maybe it's not that easy, I don't know.

Comment: @uisky Hi, have you ever resolved this? I believe one of the more reliable solutions would be to use `ZipFile.open` on a member and stream `.read(Nbytes)` in some reasonable bytes size and check if it's not too big (if so, bail), (similarly to check type, `.read(2048)` only first 2KiB and throw that into a magic library for the magic bytes check) Otherwise the zip library would have to check itself on extracting whether the currently extracted byte size is greater than the provided meta data original file size - which I suspect it ***doesn't*** do ....

Comment: **note!** if you do the `.read(2048)` **don't forget to `.seek(0)`**! before you start the actual reading!